# Undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for Namespaced Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I'm using **Devise** along with **CanCan/Rolify** for authentication for my rails app and I'm having a hard time understanding how to pass Devise methods to namespaced controllers.

I'm using a standard `users` model and controller for the main part of my app, everything on that side works well and good. However, I have set it up that if an account with a specific `role` (which is determined after registration) logs in using the main login page, it will redirect them to namespaced views and controllers.

Lets say that `user_id: 3` logs in and is redirected to `0.0.0.0/external/dashboard`, I can call Devise's `current_user` method on the `dashboard` page after redirection and returns the correct information. However, when I set a `link_to` for that user to be able to edit his profile at `0.0.0.0/external/users/3/edit` I receive the following error:

```
Started GET "/external/users/3/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-31 21:40:59 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for External::UsersController:Class)
```

**`routes`**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations', registrations: 'registrations' }

# External routes
namespace :external do
  resources :properties, :clients, :orders, :deeds, :mortgages, :users, :owners, :dashboard
end
```

**`external/dashboard view`**

```
<%= user_name_helper(current_user) %>
```

**`user_name_helper`** (produces user edit link)

```
def user_name_helper(user)
  if user.name.blank?
    link_to "Update your profile here.", edit_external_user_path(user)
  else
    "Hello, #{user.name}"
  end
end
```

Error happens when I click the link produced by this helper.

But `<%= link_to fa_icon("sign-out", text: "Logout"), destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>` works fine from `0.0.0.0/external/dashboard`.

So I am confused as to why I can call `current_user` within the view for the `External::DashboardController` but can't call it within the `External::UsersController`. All namespaced controllers inherit directly from `ApplicationController` and I want to keep only using a single `users model`. I've searched through a bunch of different articles but can't seem to find an answer with a configuration similar to mine, so can anyone explain to me what I might be doing wrong and how to get this to work as well as allowing me to have the ability to use any other `Devise methods` in my namespaced views? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I figured it out. The issue was that I was calling a conditional `before_filter` in my `external/` controllers as follows:

```
before_filter :client_only unless current_user.has_role? :admin
```

Once I removed that everything worked as intended. I still have the following `before_filter` in place which works.

```
before_filter :client_only

...

private

def client_only
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.is_client?
end
```

Not entirely sure why the conditional filter wouldn't work the way I originally had it so if anyone has any insight and feels like sharing then I'm all ears, thanks.